# Mysql upgrade 5.7.22 to 8.0, server not starting after upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, upgrade

I followed the upgrade guide [Upgrading MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html).

Already installed version of mysql is 5.7.22

Verified all Upgrade Prerequisites for MySQL 5.7 Installation

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 1;
```

then after shutdown server using below command :

```
mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

Steps followed while upgrading :

```
cd /tmp/ && wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
        (Reading database ... 8438 files and directories currently installed.)
        Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
        Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) over (0.8.10-1) ...
        Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
        debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
        debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
        debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
        Configuring mysql-apt-config
        ----------------------------

        MySQL APT Repo features MySQL Server along with a variety of MySQL components. You may select the appropriate product to choose the version
        that you wish to receive.

        Once you are satisfied with the configuration then select last option 'Ok' to save the configuration, then run 'apt-get update' to load
        package list. Advanced users can always change the configurations later, depending on their own needs.

          1. MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-5.7)  3. MySQL Preview Packages (Currently selected: Disabled)
          2. MySQL Tools & Connectors (Currently selected: Enabled)  4. Ok
        Which MySQL product do you wish to configure? 1

        This configuration program has determined that mysql-5.7 is configured on your system, and has highlighted the most appropriate repository
        package. If you are not sure which version to install, do not change the auto-selected version. Advanced users can always change the version
        as needed later. Note that MySQL Cluster also contains MySQL Server.

          1. mysql-5.7  2. mysql-8.0  3. mysql-cluster-7.5  4. mysql-cluster-7.6  5. None
        Which server version do you wish to receive? 2

        MySQL APT Repo features MySQL Server along with a variety of MySQL components. You may select the appropriate product to choose the version
        that you wish to receive.

        Once you are satisfied with the configuration then select last option 'Ok' to save the configuration, then run 'apt-get update' to load
        package list. Advanced users can always change the configurations later, depending on their own needs.

          1. MySQL Server & Cluster (Currently selected: mysql-8.0)  3. MySQL Preview Packages (Currently selected: Disabled)
          2. MySQL Tools & Connectors (Currently selected: Enabled)  4. Ok
        Which MySQL product do you wish to configure? 4

        OK

apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-server
        Configuring mysql-community-server
        ----------------------------------

        MySQL 8 uses a new authentication based on improved SHA256-based password methods. It is recommended that all new MySQL Server installations
        use this method going forward. This new authentication plugin requires new versions of connectors and clients, with support for this new 8
        authentication (caching_sha2_password). Currently MySQL 8 Connectors and community drivers built with libmysqlclient21 support this new
        method. Clients built with older versions of libmysqlclient may not be able to connect to the new server.

        To retain compatibility with older client software, the default authentication plugin can be set to the legacy value (mysql_native_password)
        This should only be done if required third-party software has not been updated to work with the new authentication method. The change will be
        written to the file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/default-auth-override.cnf

        After installation, the default can be changed by setting the default_authentication_plugin server setting.

          1. Use Strong Password Encryption (RECOMMENDED)  2. Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)
        Select default authentication plugin 2
```

after successful installation trying to start mysql server using old mysql data dir. But its not starting server :

```
mysqld_safe --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
        2018-07-12T06:46:26.378138Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
        2018-07-12T06:46:26.391934Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
        2018-07-12T06:46:26.396613Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

and there is no new error in mysql error.log :

```
2018-07-12T06:42:34.126621Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2018-07-12T06:42:34.126624Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2018-07-12T06:42:34.126724Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2018-07-12T06:42:34.126835Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-07-12T06:42:34.227213Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2018-07-12T06:42:34.227742Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 180712  6:42:34
2018-07-12T06:42:35.902099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2589862
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903598Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903608Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903616Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903618Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903719Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2018-07-12T06:42:35.903965Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-07-12T06:42:35.978195Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: You say there is no *error* in the error.log. Is there something else in it (then add it to your question) or is it empty or doesn't it exist?

Comment: @Solarflare 2018-07-12T06:42:35.978195Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. You may get support on database administration related question on the DBA or serverfault sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - no logs, no errors, a standalone console just silently closed. So, made a backup of my.ini and created a new one, with just basedir and datadir options:

```
[mysqld]
# set basedir to your installation path
basedir=c:/mysql
# set datadir to the location of your data directory
datadir=c:/mysql/data
```

Then started a standalone console, confirmed it works, and started adding options from old options file, restarting console till it not started. What I found was - "To avoid a startup failure on MySQL 8.0, remove any instance of NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER from sql_mode system variable settings in MySQL option files".

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem. To solve it I uninstalled mysql 5.7, made a backup of the / var / lib / mysql directory, then deleted the mysql directory and reinstalled version 8.0. That's the only way I could make it work. This problem occurs because mysql8.0 can not interpret the files generated in version 5.7 of mysql. especially the log files (ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0).

Here is the sequence of commands I used to solve my problem:

`sudo yum remove mysql -y
cd ..
cp -av / var / lib / mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
rm -rf mysql
sudo yum install mysql-community-server -y
service mysqld start`

And everything worked correctly.

NOTE: Since it was a new installation, I had no old databases. So just perform these procedures and work normally.

Hope this helps.